# iTextSharp - Header and Footer for all pages

Tags: pdf, header, itext, footer

I'm generating PDF by adding single PdfPTable which accommodates multiple pages.
Now I want to add header and footer to all these pages but it is only displaying on first page. Also margins are not working correctly.

I am overriding OnStartPage/OnEndPage events of class PdfPageEventHelper.

Kindly suggest best way to incorporate header and footers.

Thanks

Comment: Please show your code which *is only displaying on first page* so we can tell you how to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Header and Footer in ITextSharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484244/header-and-footer-in-itextsharp)

Answer (score 5):

Rule #1: don't use `OnStartPage()` to add a header or a footer. Use the `OnEndPage()` method only to add both the header and the footer.

Rule #2: don't add content to the `Document` object passed as a parameter to the event method. Use the `DirectContent` of the `PdfWriter` instead.

Rule #3: read the [documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com) and look at the examples and Q&As marked [header](http://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/header) and [footer](http://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/footer)

You'll notice that your question is a duplicate of:

- [How to add HTML headers and footers to a page?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-html-headers-and-footers-page) (Java example)
- [How to generate a report with dynamic header in PDF using itextsharp?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-generate-report-dynamic-header-pdf-using-itextsharp) (C# example)
- [How to add text as a header or footer?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-text-header-or-footer)
- ...

This answers your question: *Kindly suggest best way to incorporate header and footers.*

Your question about "margins not working correctly" is probably answered here: [Why is my content overlapping with my footer?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/why-my-content-overlapping-my-footer) However, saying *"margins are not working correctly"* isn't an actual question. If I tell my doctor: "I don't feel well, please help me!" I can't expect him to help me if I don't give him more info. When I add headers and footers, the margins work correctly. If it doesn't work for you, you are doing it wrong...

The same is true for your allegation that the header and footer *"is only displaying on first page."* That's simply not true from our point of view. If you add the event to a `PdfWriter` like this:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
Header event = new Header();
writer.setPageEvent(event);
```

Then the `OnEndPage()` method is invoked every time a page is finalized.

Comment: Thanks, now header footer appearing on all pages. But I have logo in Header which is align at center of page and footer contains line, i have tried to use html and convert to pdf content but line is not appearing in footer and logo shifted to rightmost corner inside header.