# iTextsharp - Repeat a html table on top of every page

Tags: c#, itext

I plan to create an invoice by using iTextsharp, Inside my invoice, it consist of 3 parts which are

1. table on top of page ( include all vendor information)
2. gridview (item of purchase)
3. signature part (only in last page of invoice)

So far I complete the gridview part using Pdfptable + splitlate

```
       PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(gv.Columns.Count);
       table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellText, fontH1)));
       ...
       ...
        //create PDF document
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, -30, -30, 15f, 15f);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        pdfDoc.Add(table);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;" + "filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
```

But I have no idea how to insert table on every page. I plan to use html table because it quite many thing need to control, like difference vendor, addrress, show/hide or cancelled image. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has been asked before. See [How to add HTML headers and footers to a page?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-html-headers-and-footers-page) in the official documentation, or take a look at [How to add HTML headers and footers to a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394158/how-to-add-html-headers-and-footers-to-a-page) on StackOverflow.

The answer by Roman Sidorov is wrong, because Roman assumes that you are triggering `NewPage()` from your code. That isn't always true. You add a table to the `Document`, and that table spans multiple pages. This means that iText triggers the `NewPage()` function internally.

You can add content to every page that is created, by using page events. The `OnEndPage()` event is triggered right before a `NewPage()` action is performed. This is when you add extra content to the current page. The `OnStartPage()` event is triggered right after a `NewPage()` action is performed. It is forbidden to add content in the `OnStartPage()` event. See [iTextSharp - Header and Footer for all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974539)

This is an example of a page event implementation in Java:

```
public class HeaderFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper {
    protected ElementList header;
    protected ElementList footer;
    public HeaderFooter() throws IOException {
        header = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(HEADER, null);
        footer = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(FOOTER, null);
    }
    @Override
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        try {
            ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
            ct.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(36, 832, 559, 810));
            for (Element e : header) {
                ct.addElement(e);
            }
            ct.go();
            ct.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(36, 10, 559, 32));
            for (Element e : footer) {
                ct.addElement(e);
            }
            ct.go();
        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
        }
    }
}
```

You can easily port it to C#. I used this answer because it was the literal answer to a literal question. However: why would you define your header (or footer) in HTML. That doesn't make sense, does it?

Why don't you just create a `PdfPTable` and add that to every page in a page event. That is explained in the answer to the question [How to add a table as a header?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-table-header) There are many other examples in the [page events](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/page-events-itext-5) section of the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Bruno Lowagie I'm thinking using HTML to do header because the table inside consist of many information like font style,image, address, telefon and so on. For me, without using html table, it is quite a big challenge for me to arrange all the information inside the header. Or you had any tutorial/solution for design the header?  Thanks for you answer again

Comment: Don't expect XML Worker to render a table *exactly the same way* as you define it in HTML. You seem to be using iTextSharp 5. In that case, you can read "iText in Action - Second Edition." The latest version however is iText 7, and how to use iText 7 is explained here: [iText 7: building blocks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/). There's a huge difference between iText 5 and iText 7.

Comment: Hi @Bruno Lowagie , Sorry Im newbie for programming, may I ask implement the iText 7 is same like iTextSharp 5? Just add the dll into visual studio as reference? Thanks

Comment: Now it's a set of DLLs, because we've made iText 7 more modular. Also: XML worker isn't available for iText 7 yet (we're working on it). The API has changed substantially.

Comment: Hi @Bruno Lowaige Sorry may i ask about the example of a page event you mention is valid for itextsharp?

Comment: I don't know C#, so I gave you the Java version. However, the page event functionality that works for iText (Java) also works for iTextSharp (C#). Obviously, you have to change some details that are inherent to the differences between Java and C# (such as changing the first letter of methods to upper-case, replacing some setters by a property notation,...). Those are things a C# developer can do eyes closed.